# C: Assign strtok token to char * Segfault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

Why do I get a segfault with the below code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char * tmp = "0.1";
    char * first = strtok(tmp, ".");
    return 0;
}
```

Edited:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char tmp[] = "0.1";
    char *first = strtok(tmp, ".");
    char *second = strtok(tmp, "."); // Yes, should be NULL
    printf("%s\n", first);       
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The segfault can be reproduced at the online gdb here:
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Comment: `char * tmp = "0.1";` makes the compiler write the string within the executable, which cannot be modified at run-time. `char tmp[] = "0.1";` will push the string onto the stack, which can be modified at run-time.

Comment: @user3121023  I see, thanks! I'm now getting a segfault again when trying to print the token: printf("%s\n", first); Do you know why?

Comment: @RayaneCTX I see, thanks! After making that change, that line no longer segfaults, but I'm getting a segfult when trying to print the token: printf("%s\n", first);

Comment: @user3121023 Done.

Comment: can you try using the online gdb in the link? I'm using that and It's giving me a sefgault.

Comment: Even with the change to `tmp[]` there is still a problem. The first `strtok` will _modify_ `tmp` in place and leave `tmp` as `0`. So, the second `strtok` will get `0` and _not_ `1` as I suspect you want (because it sees `0` and not the original `0.1`). You'd need to do: `second = strtok(NULL,".")` to get `1`

Comment: @user3121023 You are right, I should've used NULL, but yeah I'm still getting the segfault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your first code is that `tmp` points at a string literal, which is read-only. When `strtok` tries to modify the string, it crashes.

---

The problem with your second code is a missing include:

```
#include <string.h>
```

This missing header means `strtok` is undeclared in your program. The C compiler assumes all undeclared functions return `int`. This is not true for `strtok`, which returns `char *`. The likely cause of the crash in your example is that the code is running on a 64-bit machine where pointers are 8 bytes wide but `int` is only 4 bytes. This messes up the return value of `strtok`, so `first` is a garbage pointer (and `printf` crashes when it tries to use it).

You can confirm this for yourself by doing

```
char *first = strtok(tmp, ".");
printf("%p %p\n", (void *)tmp, (void *)first);
```

The addresses printed for `tmp` and `first` should be identical (and they are if you `#include <string.h>`).

---

The funny thing is that gcc can warn you about these problems:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:6:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strtok' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     char *first = strtok(tmp, ".");
                   ^
main.c:6:19: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
main.c:7:20: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     char *second = strtok(tmp, "."); // Yes, should be NULL
                    ^
```

... and onlinegdb will show you these warnings, but only if compilation fails!

So to see compiler warnings on onlinegdb, you have to add a hard error to the code (e.g. by putting a `@` in the last line of the file).

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of the function `strtok` goes something like this:

1. Accept a string `str` or NULL and a string of delimiters characters.
2. The strtok function then begins to process the given string `str`, wherein which it reads the string character by character until it encounters a character present amongst the provided delimiter characters.
3. If the number of characters it has encountered until reaching the delimiter string is > 0, then replace the delimiter character by '\n' and returns a pointer to the first character in this iteration which was not a delimiter character.
4. Else, if the number of characters it has encountered until reaching the delimiter string is == 0, then continue iterating the rest of the string without replacing this delimiter character by '\n'.

I've created some code snippets which will help you better understand the nature of the function, https://ideone.com/6NCcrR and https://ideone.com/KVI5n4 (<- taking excerpts from your code your code)

> Now to answer your question, including `string.h` header and setting
>   `char tmp[] = "0.1";` should solve your issue.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. The question is "why does this code segfault?", not "how do I make the segfault go away?".

Comment: Yep, you're right. Just wanted to give a bit insight about how the strtok functions internally. By the time I wrote the explanation, the issue had already been discussed thoroughly and hence I decided to cut short. Anyways, I think it'll still serve a little purpose to anyone who lands here so might as well let it stay :)

Answer (score 2):

With `char * tmp = "0.1";`, `tmp` points to a string literal that cannot be modified and `strtok` tries to modify the string by replacing `.` with `'\0'`.

Another approach, avioding the segfault, would be to use `strchr` to find the dot and the precision field to print a limited number of characters. The sub-strings may be copied to other variables as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char * tmp = "0.1";
    char * first = strchr(tmp, '.');
    char * second = first + 1;
    if ( first) {
        printf ( "%.*s\n", first - tmp, tmp);
        printf ( "%s\n", second);
    }
    printf ( "Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's cool and all, but I don't see how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

tmp is **not a string literal** as few answers or comments point out.

char *tmp = "0.1" this is a **string literal**.

char tmp[] = "0.1" is a **character array** and all array operations can be performed on them.

The segfault arises because the **function declaration** for strtok is not found as **string.h** is not included, and the gcc or other c compilers implicitly declare the **return type as int** by default.

Now depending on the platform the integer size may vary, if int size is **4 byte** and pointer size is **8 byte** respectively

> char *first = (int)strtok(tmp,".");

**Truncation** takes place on the pointer address returned by strtok and then when your printing, you are **de-referencing** the address value contained in first which could be a memory region out of bound resulting in segmentation fault or undefined behavior.

If you can typecast the output of strtok to a type that is 8 bytes(long in my case) then there would not be a segfault, although this is not a clean way to do.

**Include proper headerfiles** to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: Neither of your two examples is a string literal. `"0.1"` is a string literal; your lines show a variable definition (with an initializer). The first one declares `tmp` as a pointer (and initializes it with a string literal), the second one declares `tmp` as an array (and initializes it with a string literal). If a function is declared with the wrong return type, casting the result to a different type will not fix it.

Comment: the first example char *tmp = "0.1", make tmp point to read-only memory where "0.1" is stored. In second case char tmp[] = "0.1" allocates memory for the string and copies the string into it, so modifying it is valid. And string literals are allocated in read-only.

Comment: As you said "0.1" is a string literal as per the definition as a sequence of characters surrounded by double quotes. But modifying tmp is valid as its an array of characters. And I did say its not a clean way to do the casting to a different type hope you read my point. Its only suggested to see why the segfault occurred.